# Openshift Origin Node scaling

Tags: openshift-origin

We are testing openshift origin (Latest) for a poc. We have researched POD scaling and it has worked for us very well. [This](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#adding-nodes) talks about adding nodes and can be done with ansible/puppet but how does one completely automate this.

```
    Using openshift how does one achieve - 
        1. Create new ec2 node when current nodes are at capacity. 
           ( eg a POD which is guaranteed certain resources cannot be created ) 
        2. Add this node to current cluster 
        3. Scale PODs to this node
```

Comment: I do that automation  but in AWS whit Ansible tower because you need a callback to launch the configuration when the provisioning has finished

Comment: Appreciate your reply. Thanks I guess what I do not know is how can openshift trigger that automatically.When a POD is unable to deploy due to resource limitation, how can this trigger an event that will then be used to stand up another node ( either by ansible/autoscale )

Comment: The best indicator today is pods that can't schedule (the set of pods with spec.nodeName empty).  There should also be an event fired (if you "watch" all events via the API) that is FailedToFindFit (or similar) that the scheduler sends.  You can watch for this event and or pods in this state and then trigger a node creation.  In the future I would like to make this easier to script.